# Stacked bar plot with 4 categorical variables in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

My problem is being able to displaying 4 categorical variables in a bar graph in R.

The 4 categorical variables each have 2 or more levels.  My thoughts were to use a `ggplot` to create separate bar plots using `geom_bar` for each of 3 categories, for which counts of each level would be stacked.  I would then use  `facet_wrap` then to split it out by the 4th category.

The data looks like this:

```
Species     Crown_Class     Life_class      Stem_Category
E. obliqua  Suppressed      Standing live   Large stems
E. rubida   Intermediate    Standing live   Large stems
E. obliqua  Suppressed      Standing live   Small stems
E. obliqua  Suppressed      Standing live   Small stems
E. rubida   Suppressed      Standing live   Large stems
E. radiata  Suppressed      Standing live   Small stems
E. obliqua  Dominant        Standing live   Small stems
E. obliqua  Suppressed      Standing live   Small stems
E. radiata  Suppressed      Standing live   Large stems
E. rubida   NA              Standing dead   Large stems
E. rubida   Intermediate    Standing live   Large stems
```

The graph I have in mind shows each a stacked bar for each of three categories which are then grouped by a third.  For the data given, separate bars for Crown_Class, life_class and Stem_Category would be displayed for each of the species.

I have been trying for hours and can do separate plots using this code (I separated the data into 3 separate dataframes to do it though:

```
ggplot(data= cc, aes(x= Species, fill = Crown_Class))+
geom_bar(position='stack')

ggplot(data=lc, aes(x = Species, fill = Life_class))+
geom_bar(position ='stack')

ggplot(data=sc, aes(x = Species, fill = Stem_Category))+
geom_bar(position ='stack')
```

The idea was to do something like this:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data= cc, aes(x = Species, fill = Crown_Class), 
      position='stack') +
  geom_bar(data=lc, aes(x = Species, fill = Life_class), 
      position ='dodge')+
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

But the result is not what I have in mind.  The second plot effectively overwrites the first.

[image]

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just like that, how do you deal with the NAs?

Comment: You could try using [facet_grid](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_grid.html)

Comment: Sorry - my image was slightly wrong.  Have just changed it. @ArtificialBreeze, the second plot overwrites the first - you can see the colours behind.  Re: NA"s that's another problem - using `na.rm = TRUE` is probable the way.

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball but `facet_grid' will give me another block.  The aim is to get the 3 bars within 3 facets.

Comment: ok good, I was thinking you don't deal with them which could cause an issue with the plots sometimes

Comment: They sure can @ArtificialBreeze

Comment: What if you do something like `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` ?

Comment: Great minds!  I tried that too but must have had the syntax wrong.  I tried putting it before the three plots in the first example and then straight after the `ggplot()` in the second example but neither worked.  Do you know the right place for it to go?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how you could use `facet_grid` to include all 4 variables on the same plot.

Note that I generate some dummy data, since I had trouble importing your dataset into `R`.

#### generate data

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(s1 = sample(letters[1:3], 11, replace = T),
                  s2 = sample(letters[4:6], 11, replace = T),
                  s3 = sample(letters[7:9], 11, replace = T),
                  s4 = sample(letters[10:12], 11, replace = T),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

## edit:

Maybe this is closer to what you're after:

```
ggplot(df1)+
    geom_bar(aes(x = s1), position = 'stack')+
    geom_bar(aes(x = s2), position = 'stack')+
    geom_bar(aes(x = s3), position = 'stack')+
    facet_wrap(~ s4)
```

[image]

If you proceed in this manner, you should definitely note that the values on the x-axis come from **three different variables**.

*IMHO: While I'm no expert on the subject, I do think it's a bit dubious to create a visualization with three different variables on the same axis, and `ggplot2` gives you plenty of options to avoid proceeding in such a manner.*

#### make plot using `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = s1, fill = s2))+
    geom_bar(position = 'stack')+
    facet_grid(s3~s4)
```

[image]

#### make plot using `interaction` and `facet_wrap`

Now, suppose you don't want the two grouping factors as facets, and just prefer one facet. Then, we can use the `interaction` function.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = s1, fill = interaction(s2,s3)))+
    geom_bar(position = 'stack')+
    facet_wrap(~s4)
```

[image]

#### use `Rmisc::multiplot`

Finally, we can create three separate plots, and then use `Rmisc::multiplot` to plot on the same page.

```
library(Rmisc)
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = s1, fill = s2))+
    geom_bar(position = 'stack')
p2 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = s1, fill = s3))+
    geom_bar(position = 'stack')
p3 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = s1, fill = s4))+
    geom_bar(position = 'stack')

multiplot(p1,p2,p3, cols = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but it's not quite giving the result I'm after - the aim is to get something where there is no interaction between the first 3 categories.  They just need to be displayed as stacked bars showing the count of each level in the category for the 4th category.  Almost as if all three of the first categories were on the x axis and their count in the y axis.  And then split up by the fourth category.

Comment: @AlisonBennett so three different variables would be grouped on the same axis?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?

Comment: Thanks again, it's almost there but now not stacking properly. ie. in your example a, b and c should be stacked.  NB. I hear your comment - but because the total count of each of the categorical variables is the same - I think it is reasonable to do this plot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to differentiate your plots using `Crown_Class`, `Life_class`, and `Stem_Category`, ggplot2 would prefer those values to be in a column of their own (in general ggplot2 like long data, where only one column contains the value being plotted.) We can reorganize the data using tidyr.

```
library(tidyr)
df <-
  gather(df, variable, value, -Species)

head(df)
     Species    variable           value
1 E. obliqua Crown_Class      Suppressed
2  E. rubida Crown_Class    Intermediate
3 E. obliqua Crown_Class      Suppressed
4 E. obliqua Crown_Class      Suppressed
5  E. rubida Crown_Class      Suppressed
6 E. radiata Crown_Class      Suppressed
```

Now we can facet wrap on `variable`

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

If you dont like having only one guide for all the colors for `Crown_Class`, `Life_class` and 'Stem_Category', you can make three separate plots and combine them using the `gridExtra` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
p <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable == 'Crown_Class') %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)

q <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable == 'Life_class') %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)

r <-
  df %>%
  filter(variable == 'Stem_Category') %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, fill = value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)

grid.arrange(p, q, r)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I like this answer, not quite what I was aiming for, but does provide a good solution.  I'm having a little trouble with the `gridExtra` option.  When I run the grid.arrange section this error occurs 'Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting` - do you know what it is?

Comment: @AlisonBennett That error means that something happened with the `facet_wrap` call in the plots p, q, and r somewhere. Did you run the `gather ` command on the data?

Comment: Sorry.  my bad.  One of my variables was not named correctly.  I like your answer and thanks for your help - i also like the one by @bouncyball. I'll play with it more tomorrow and accept one.  You have certainly taught me a lot - thanks.  Now please don't think I'm rude, but it's waaaay past my bedtime.